# Guidance on exceptions given by the Python docs

Tags: python, exception

According to the Python documentation on idioms and anti-idioms [in relation to exceptions](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#exceptions): "You should try to use as few except clauses in your code as you can — the ones you do use will usually be inside calls which should always succeed, or a catch-all in a main function." Taking this sentence in sections...

> "You should try to use as few except clauses in your code as you can"

A bit confusing for a newbie like myself, I thought it was good practise in Python to use the [EAFP](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-eafp) style -i.e. many `try` and `except` statements. Or am I missing the point?

> "the ones you do use will usually be inside calls which should always succeed"

I don't understand the point that's being made here.

> "or a catch-all in a main function."

So it's good style to any let code that throws an exception to simply pass it up the call stack until it reaches the top level where you have really generic exception handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the first point, the *whole point* of using exceptions is that you don't have to wrap every line in one! E.g. in C, errors are usually determined by the return value of a function call. So you have to check those after every call if you want to catch all errors. With Python you can group a (possibly large) block of statements that go together in a try/except block and only deal with *all* errors *once*.

The second point is that (if possible) you want to solve failures close to the point where they occur. E.g. you are reading data from a network and get zero bytes. In that case it is usually perfectly allright to wait and try again.

The last point is that sometimes an error is so big that it cannot be handled at a low level. E.g. if you are trying to open a file that not exist, it wil fail. And your program cannot do whatever it was going to do with the contents of the file. It is best to handle that at the top level of the program and ask the user for another file name or maybe quit the program.

Answer (score 2):

> "You should try to use as few except clauses in your code as you can"

It's easy to litter your code with exceptions:

```
def solve_linear(mat1, mat2):
    det1 = determinant(mat1)
    det2 = determinant(mat2)
    try:
        return det1 / det2
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        raise NoSolution
```

Here, it's probably fine to let the `ZeroDivisionError` propagate.  You don't need to catch it.

> "the ones you do use will usually be inside calls which should always succeed"

For example, look at this code which reads a file, or returns a cached value.  It normally succeeds, in spite of the `KeyError` exception:

```
def read_file(path):
    try:
        return cache[path]
    except KeyError:
        fp = open(path, 'rb')
        data = fp.read()
        fp.close()
        cache[path] = data
        return data
```

> "or a catch-all in a main function."

If your program is interactive, you'll probably want to catch almost everything at the top level.  Here's the top loop of an interactive command-line program:

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            text = raw_input('enter command: ')
            cmd = parse_command(text)
        except EOFError:
            return
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            return
        except ValueError:
            print 'Syntax error'
            continue

        try:
            run_cmd(cmd)
        except SystemExit:
            raise
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()
```

Comment: +1 This, together and Roland Smith's answer, helps me get a better idea of exceptions. Hard to know which to choose as the answer. If I understand correctly, we only use `except` at the possible failure point where there's actually something useful we can do to resolve the failure, hence the `raise NoSolution` example above -and the same idea in your second example. Otherwise you might as well let it propagate to the top level.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is that exceptions should be used only for 'exceptional' circumstances. That is the meaning behind the use "in calls which will usually succeed". An example of this might be some computation that under some really weird circumstances ends having to do a division by zero. Then you can enclose that in a try / except statement to deal with that possibility.

The catch-all in a main function would be applicable to the same scenario. Say your calculations end up with a division by zero somewhere deep in the call stack. From this point you can't continue, so there's no point in having a try/except statement right at the point of failure. It would make more sense to just have one at a higher level where you can reasonably recover from the error.

The example they give in the documentation is an example of this. When calling 'get_status' you would expect the file to be there. If it doesn't then you have the except statement to deal with that (although, as mentioned, in that particular case the 'with' statement is much better).

Answer (score 1):

The Python philosophy is typically to "ask forgiveness, not permission." But the idea isn't to use a try-except clause to catch ALL possible errors. Ideally, each try-except will only catch the error(s) that are relevant.

BAD (doesn't specify a specific exception type):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
i = 3
try:
    print a[i]
except:
    print "Not found!"
```

GOOD (only handles the exception we expect to get):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
i = 3
try:
    print a[i]
except IndexError:
    print "Not found!"
```

The reason this is important is so we don't obscure other possible code errors. What if, in this example, `i` was 1.8? The first example would print `Not Found!`, obscuring the real issue, but the second example would return `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float` letting us know that there's a logical flaw in our code.

Comment: I believe this relates to a slightly different point (discussed in [another section](http://docs.python.org/howto/doanddont.html#except) of the same style guide).

Comment: @mr_c You're absolutely correct; I'll leave the answer up since I think it's good try/except advice, but this answer certainly doesn't answer the question as it was asked.